# Can't do full install (Jolnir 6.1 / Macbook Pro hardware)

Tags: install

first-time Elementary user struggling to diagnose an install failure.

Following standard instructions on https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation - Checksum hash is fine; and I can boot from the USB and use the demo.

When I try to do a full install, the installer appears to run without issues, then reboots into a black screen with a partially visible [OK] Passed notice in the top-left corner.

After waiting 30 minutes, powered off the machine and removed USB stick.

Tried rebooting the machine, and after the start-up chime, I get a rainbow of graphics failure in a very small part of the top-left of the screen.

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have the stable version of 6.1. I tried to install it to a USB, but it hangs here every time:

INFO: starting extracting step
INFO: Extracting /cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs
DEBUG: "unsquashfs" "-f" "-d" "tmp/distinst.Q5bl9tzlZmEh" "/cdrom/casper - filesystem.squashfs"
ERROR:  extracting error: archive extraction failed with status: exit status: 1